# Reading multiple recordsets

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I have a Stored proc which returns 6 select statement results.
I'm trying to use one record set to execute sp and get records for each select statement 
but i get 0 or empty records when i read them,

How can i query record set with
    multiple select statements from
    stored procedure?

ex:

```
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")     
strSql = "Exec [dbo].[xyz] '"&param1&"', '"&param2&"', '"&param3& "'"   
rs.open strSql,CN,3,3       

    Do While Not rs.EOF 
        if rs.recordcount > 0 then
            r1 = rs.GetString(, , ", ", "<BR>" ) 
        else
            r1 = 0
        end if
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop    

    Set rs = rs.NextRecordset()
        Do While Not rs.EOF 
        if rs.recordcount > 0 then
            r2 = rs.GetString(, , ", ", "<BR>" ) 
        else
            r2 = 0
        end if
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`rs.NextRecordset()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677539%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the right way to get to the next recordset returned from a stored procedure or other command, so your code snipped should work.

What is not working for you?

As an aside, I hope the `strSql` variable is not constructed the way you posted (`strSql = "Exec [dbo].[xyz] '"&param1&"', '"&param2&"', '"&param3& "'"`), as this is a clear [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability.

Comment: i changed it to command object and parameters. But i get 0 record count when i execute them

Comment: Are you certain the recordsets returned are not empty?

Comment: yes i checked using response.write(rs.recordcount) and i get -1

Comment: This does not mean the recordset has something in it. rs.RecordCount would return -1 when ADO cannot determine the number of records or if the provider or cursor type does not support RecordCount.

Comment: ok, but if i want to do this r1 = rs.GetString(, , ", ", "<BR>" )
how should i check if records are there?

Comment: i used if not rs.eof to check if it has values but i need to get count also