# How to get Values from Stored procedure when procedure has two select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

see i have stored procedure which contain two select statement , please tell me how can i get two result set from single stored procedure.
Here is code ---

```
create proc spReturnsDataFromTwoTable

As

Begin

select * from TableOne

select * from TableTwo

End
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: With T-SQL (MSSQL) this is possible if you use ; after each select. See a sample B here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @eckes: a) that is not what the user is asking for, and b) that is not correct regardless of what the user is asking for. The user wants to consume the results that are being returned in multiple result sets, quite likely either in app code or in a temp table. Also, the semicolon is not required (at least not here) and would not change the behavior of this code. The code is working, but the user just doesn't know how to make use of the second result set (most likely).

Comment: How are you calling the stored procedure? Is it an application written in c# or any other language or in the Sql Server it self inside any different procedure? Please certify.

Comment: Depending on how you are accessing your database this might help [Reading multiple recordsets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313389/reading-multiple-recordsets)

Comment: Is there any common values between both tables.or let me post what kind of output you required?

Comment: Actually in the interview some one asked the question to me . How to return value using this procedure

Comment: without knowing more it is hard to answer but my first reaction is `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can access yours two tables using data adapter:

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
  SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("procedureName", sqlConn);
  sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  sqlConn.Open();
  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  sda.Fill(ds);
  sqlconn.Close();

  // Retrieving yours stored tables from a DataSet.
  DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
  DataTable dt2 = ds.Tables[1];
```